# how to fetch exact data from mysql table in month date condition

Tags: php, mysql

hello everyone for my erp system i want some specific type of data fetch from database
for example if i want number of row added in current month purchase then i use

```
select count(receive_no) FROM tbl where contact_id=".$contactid." AND MONTH(created_on) = MONTH(CURDATE());
```

but it gets false results
and if i want sum of result in current month then i use

```
select sum(price) FROM tbl where contact_id=".$contactid." AND MONTH(created_on) = MONTH(CURDATE())
```

and if i want today date number of row or purchase then i use

```
select count(receive_no) FROM tbl where contact_id=".$contactid." AND created_on >= CURDATE()
```

so as if i want today sum of purchase then i use

```
select sum(price) FROM tbl where contact_id=".$contactid." AND created_on >= CURDATE()
```

my table created on field datetime like 2016-09-01 11:56:45
so please suggest me better query to fetch exact data
thanks

Comment: What is wrong with the results you get?

Comment: It's not really clear what - if any - the problem is with the last 3 queries, but the first one will get you the data from this month this year *and* this month last year, the year before that, etc. etc.

Comment: What @jeroen said, plus these queries will only work if you run them on a day within the month you want results from. So if you run them on the first of September they will report september data and not as you may have liked August's data

Comment: @RiggsFolly sir i received sum of current month price but its wrong

Comment: for example if i have 7 rows of price then i want sum of price with current month

Comment: In what way is it wrong. Without some example data and an example result we are **working in the dark here**

Comment: Timestamp types are stored as utc+0 in database. When you query them they are converted to your time zone. Not sure but maybe this causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what - if any - the problem is with the last 3 queries, but the first one will get you the data from this month this year *and* this month last year, the year before that, etc. etc.

So what you need is something like (there are several ways to write that...):

```
select count(receive_no) FROM tbl where 
        contact_id=".$contactid." 
    AND MONTH(created_on) = MONTH(CURDATE())
    AND YEAR(created_on) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```